# How to create a paint application like Messenger's emoji paint on captured photo in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, paint

So I'm making an app which needs to paint garland, light bulbs and other decoration. I have a code which will make an imageview on Action_Move but the app crashes. see the code below

```
fun drawLights(){
     val listener = View.OnTouchListener(function = { view, motionEvent ->
         val x = motionEvent.getX()
         val y = motionEvent.getY()
         when (motionEvent.action){
             MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                 Toast.makeText(this,"Action Down",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
             }
             MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Moving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                 ////Imageview Creation Here using late init var
             }
             MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                 Toast.makeText(this,"Done" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
             }
         }
         true
     })
     edit_Canvas.setOnTouchListener(listener)
}
```

Does anyone here know any blog related to this or already resolved this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I think your code is crashing because of out of memory if you are creating an ImageView on ACTION_MOVE. onTouch is being called everytime you touch the screen so it wil eventually do alot of calls.

Comment: Yes technically, how can I do it in a proper way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for topics on drawing on the Android Canvas. There are lots of sample codes out there

This one's from the official documentation in drawing on the Canvas https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing

Comment: i have already looked something like what you've provide but nothing seems to solve my task :(

Comment: The links I've sent is enough to equip you with the right tools to do the job. You should not add an ImageView everytime but draw the image on a canvas on move. An ImageView is a full view which requires more memory to show. Canvas just draws into the screen.